# WinPcap C# Wrapping pcap_findalldevs() throws PInvokeStackImbalance

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, wrapper, winpcap

Im trying to write a C# wrapper for winpcap. It gives the warning PInvokeStackImbalance when im trying to debug, but pcap_findalldevs does its job. But I think this will cause a memory leak in program. Btw this code is from networkminer i didnt write this just trying to understand winpcap and wrapping.
    This is the method in WinPcap

```
int pcap_findalldevs( pcap_if_t **  alldevsp, char * errbuf )
```

This is what i wrote in my program

```
[DllImport("wpcap.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern int pcap_findalldevs(ref IntPtr alldevsp, StringBuilder errbuf);

i = IntPtr.Zero;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);

if (pcap_findalldevs(ref i, stringBuilder) == -1)
            return null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `cdecl` calling convention:

```
[DllImport("wpcap.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
```

The default calling convention for `DllImport` is `stdcall` but I'd bet that the WinPcap library is exported as `cdecl`.

Comment: ty so much but whats the meaning of PInvokeStackImbalance? it was still doing its job

Comment: Both stdcall and cdecl push parameters onto the stack right to left. They differ in who cleans up the stack. Callee cleans up for stdcall and caller cleans up for cdecl. The latter is what enables variadic functions in C. Your PInvokeStackImbalance warning detects that the stack wasn't cleaned up by the caller as it should have been and warns you. You probably get away with it because the stack gets realigned before damage is done. But you won't always get away with it. You must get your calling conventions to match.